# Deleting struct with an object in it

Tags: c++

I have a struct like this:

```
struct CalendarEntry
{
    Date DueDate;
    std::string Subject;
    CalendarEntry* pLeft = nullptr;
    CalendarEntry* pRight = nullptr;
};
```

Date is a class without dynamic data, using default constructor.
If I have a struct object do I have to delete the Date-Object before or is the destructor of Date called automatically?

```
CalendarEntry* mRoot = new CalendarEntry;
//delete &mRoot->DueDate;
delete mRoot;
mRoot = nullptr;
```

Another small question, I have a struct, which is only used inside one class.
Currently I have it defined in the Header, above the class.
But when it is only used inside the class, is it better to define it inside the class as private?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Why are you using `new` to allocate your object on the heap? Why not simply do `CalendarEntry mRoot;`?

Comment: something that is often misunderstood in c++: destructors are always called automatically unless you explicitly ask for something else (eg by using `new`)

Comment: @JesperJuhl because the struct is used for a binary tree, and mRoot points to the root struct of the tree. Is homework from university, to programm a calendar, where the appointments are saved in a binary tree acording to DueDate from class Date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I have a struct object do I have to delete the Date-Object before

No.

> or is the destructor of Date called automatically?

Yes. Sub objects such as members and base sub objects are always destroyed by the destructor of the super object.

Comment: "always destroyed by the destructor of the <strike>super</strike> containing object" if the destructor for the containing object runs... right now it appears that objects found at `*pLeft` and `*pRight` will probably get leaked, and the `Date` subobjects within *those* would not be destroyed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because the scope of date ends when the scope of calendar entry ends, if date had dynamic memory make sure you delete it in date's destructor.

Comment: i am not sure if "scope" is the right word here, the scope of `mRoot` does not end at `delete mRoot;`